# EF6 - Correct SQL output but data does not populate

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, many-to-many

I am attempting to populate a child entity of a reference table entity using a many-to-many relationship.

I have 3 tables: Addresses, Members, and MemberAddresses. Addresses and Members have a collection of MemberAddresses each. MemberAddresses has a single Address and Member object with a composite key. Here are the related mappings:

**Addresses**

```
HasMany(x => x.MemberAddresses).WithRequired(x => x.Address).HasForeignKey(x => x.AddressId);
```

**Members**

```
HasMany(x => x.MemberAddresses).WithRequired(x => x.Member).HasForeignKey(x => x.MemberId);
```

**MemberAddresses**

```
HasRequired(rp => rp.Member).WithMany(x => x.MemberAddresses).HasForeignKey(rp => rp.MemberId);
```

When I attmempt to do the following, I am not getting any of the child objects loaded into the Local extension (i.e. both Address and Member are null):

```
_context.MemberAddresses.Include(rp => rp.Address).Where(rp => rp.MemberId == member.MemberId).Load();
```

What's interesting is that the output SQL from EF is doing the correct fetch (I checked this against SQL Server). If I attempt to use a linq query with ToList(), it works as intended. It seems to be loading specifically will not work, and doesn't populate the child objects.

**EDIT**
For some added clarity, I attempted to use a simple linq query syntax to accomplish the same result:

```
            var results = (from ma in _context.MemberAddresses
                       where ma.MemberId == parentMember.MemberId
                       select ma).Include(x => x.Address).Include(x => x.Member).ToList();
```

This was able to populate results with the fully populated list of MemberAddresses. However, it was NOT being added to the _context.MemberAddresses.Local instance.

What is even stranger, if I first use the linq query, then perform the load lineI have above, the results now remove the child objects from memory. That is, it will still have the ID's for both child tables, but loses the child object instances.

Answer (score 0):

I can't repro any difference in using Load() and enumerating the results.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

namespace Ef6Test
{

    public class Address
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<MemberAddress> MemberAddresses { get; } = new HashSet<MemberAddress>();
    }
    public class Member
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<MemberAddress> MemberAddresses { get; } = new HashSet<MemberAddress>();
    }
    public class MemberAddress

    {
        public Address Address { get; set; }
        [Key( ), Column(Order =0)]
        public int AddressId { get; set; }
        public Member  Member{ get; set; }

        [Key(), Column(Order = 1)]
        public int MemberId{ get; set; }

    }
    class Db : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Address> Address { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Member> Member{ get; set; }
        public DbSet<MemberAddress> MemberAddresses { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        }
    }




    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Db>());

            using (var db = new Db())
            {
                db.Database.Initialize(true);


                var m = new Member();

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    var a = new Address();
                    var ma = new MemberAddress();
                    ma.Address = a;
                    ma.Member = m;
                    db.Address.Add(a);
                    db.MemberAddresses.Add(ma);
                }


                db.Member.Add(m);
                db.SaveChanges();

            }

            Console.WriteLine("Enumerating Include Query");
            using (var db = new Db())
            {

                db.Database.Log = m => Console.WriteLine(m);

                var list = db.MemberAddresses.Include(rp => rp.Address).Where(rp => rp.MemberId < 10).ToList();

                foreach (var e in db.ChangeTracker.Entries())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Entity.GetType().Name);
                }
                var a = db.ChangeTracker.Entries<MemberAddress>().First();
                Console.WriteLine($"Address IsLoaded: {a.Reference<Address>("Address").IsLoaded}");

                Console.WriteLine($"Member Local {db.Member.Local.Count} items");
                foreach (var member in db.Member.Local)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Member {member.Id}");
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"MemberAddress Local {db.MemberAddresses.Local.Count} items");
                foreach (var ma in db.MemberAddresses.Local)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"MemberAddress {ma.MemberId},{ma.AddressId}");
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"Address Local {db.Address.Local.Count} items");
                foreach (var ad in db.Address.Local)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Address {ad.Id}");
                }


            }

            Console.WriteLine("Using Load()");
            using (var db = new Db())
            {

                db.Database.Log = m => Console.WriteLine(m);

                db.MemberAddresses.Include(rp => rp.Address).Where(rp => rp.MemberId < 10).Load();

                foreach (var e in db.ChangeTracker.Entries())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Entity.GetType().Name);
                }
                var a = db.ChangeTracker.Entries<MemberAddress>().First();
                Console.WriteLine($"Address IsLoaded: {a.Reference<Address>("Address").IsLoaded}");

                Console.WriteLine($"Member Local {db.Member.Local.Count} items");
                foreach (var member in db.Member.Local)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Member {member.Id}");
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"MemberAddress Local {db.MemberAddresses.Local.Count} items");
                foreach (var ma in db.MemberAddresses.Local)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"MemberAddress {ma.MemberId},{ma.AddressId}");
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"Address Local {db.Address.Local.Count} items");
                foreach (var ad in db.Address.Local)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Address {ad.Id}");
                }

            }



            Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

outputs

```
Enumerating Include Query
Opened connection at 12/6/2017 8:33:59 AM -06:00

SELECT
    [Extent1].[AddressId] AS [AddressId],
    [Extent1].[MemberId] AS [MemberId]
    FROM [dbo].[MemberAddresses] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[MemberId] < 10


-- Executing at 12/6/2017 8:34:00 AM -06:00

-- Completed in 15 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 12/6/2017 8:34:00 AM -06:00

MemberAddress
Address_B9AEC76E2DAA985CBBFB722E4D5F60354D0FC4633617474BEE39DD928330C226
MemberAddress
Address_B9AEC76E2DAA985CBBFB722E4D5F60354D0FC4633617474BEE39DD928330C226
MemberAddress
Address_B9AEC76E2DAA985CBBFB722E4D5F60354D0FC4633617474BEE39DD928330C226
MemberAddress
Address_B9AEC76E2DAA985CBBFB722E4D5F60354D0FC4633617474BEE39DD928330C226
MemberAddress
Address_B9AEC76E2DAA985CBBFB722E4D5F60354D0FC4633617474BEE39DD928330C226
MemberAddress
Address_B9AEC76E2DAA985CBBFB722E4D5F60354D0FC4633617474BEE39DD928330C226
MemberAddress
Address_B9AEC76E2DAA985CBBFB722E4D5F60354D0FC4633617474BEE39DD928330C226
MemberAddress
Address_B9AEC76E2DAA985CBBFB722E4D5F60354D0FC4633617474BEE39DD928330C226
MemberAddress
Address_B9AEC76E2DAA985CBBFB722E4D5F60354D0FC4633617474BEE39DD928330C226
MemberAddress
Address_B9AEC76E2DAA985CBBFB722E4D5F60354D0FC4633617474BEE39DD928330C226
Address IsLoaded: True
Member Local 0 items
MemberAddress Local 10 items
MemberAddress 1,1
MemberAddress 1,2
MemberAddress 1,3
MemberAddress 1,4
MemberAddress 1,5
MemberAddress 1,6
MemberAddress 1,7
MemberAddress 1,8
MemberAddress 1,9
MemberAddress 1,10
Address Local 10 items
Address 1
Address 2
Address 3
Address 4
Address 5
Address 6
Address 7
Address 8
Address 9
Address 10
Using Load()
Opened connection at 12/6/2017 8:34:00 AM -06:00

SELECT
    [Extent1].[AddressId] AS [AddressId],
    [Extent1].[MemberId] AS [MemberId]
    FROM [dbo].[MemberAddresses] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[MemberId] < 10


-- Executing at 12/6/2017 8:34:00 AM -06:00

-- Completed in 8 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 12/6/2017 8:34:00 AM -06:00

MemberAddress
Address_B9AEC76E2DAA985CBBFB722E4D5F60354D0FC4633617474BEE39DD928330C226
MemberAddress
Address_B9AEC76E2DAA985CBBFB722E4D5F60354D0FC4633617474BEE39DD928330C226
MemberAddress
Address_B9AEC76E2DAA985CBBFB722E4D5F60354D0FC4633617474BEE39DD928330C226
MemberAddress
Address_B9AEC76E2DAA985CBBFB722E4D5F60354D0FC4633617474BEE39DD928330C226
MemberAddress
Address_B9AEC76E2DAA985CBBFB722E4D5F60354D0FC4633617474BEE39DD928330C226
MemberAddress
Address_B9AEC76E2DAA985CBBFB722E4D5F60354D0FC4633617474BEE39DD928330C226
MemberAddress
Address_B9AEC76E2DAA985CBBFB722E4D5F60354D0FC4633617474BEE39DD928330C226
MemberAddress
Address_B9AEC76E2DAA985CBBFB722E4D5F60354D0FC4633617474BEE39DD928330C226
MemberAddress
Address_B9AEC76E2DAA985CBBFB722E4D5F60354D0FC4633617474BEE39DD928330C226
MemberAddress
Address_B9AEC76E2DAA985CBBFB722E4D5F60354D0FC4633617474BEE39DD928330C226
Address IsLoaded: True
Member Local 0 items
MemberAddress Local 10 items
MemberAddress 1,1
MemberAddress 1,2
MemberAddress 1,3
MemberAddress 1,4
MemberAddress 1,5
MemberAddress 1,6
MemberAddress 1,7
MemberAddress 1,8
MemberAddress 1,9
MemberAddress 1,10
Address Local 10 items
Address 1
Address 2
Address 3
Address 4
Address 5
Address 6
Address 7
Address 8
Address 9
Address 10
Hit any key to exit
```

Comment: Whether or not the child object is "loaded" doesn't seem to matter. Please see my edit for clarity.

Comment: Also, you put an Id on the MemberAddress table. That is inaccurate. It should be a composite key between the 2 tables.

Comment: Updated the post.  Still no repro.  See if you can modify get the code I posted to reproduce your issue.